# Upwards Tree Traverse in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, tree, psql

I have the following tables in OracleDB 12c

Categories Table:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| CATEGORY_ID | PARENT_ID |     DESCRIPTION     |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
|           1 | (null)    | Category 1          |
|           2 | (null)    | Category 2          |
|           3 | (null)    | Category 3          |
|           4 | (null)    | Category 4          |
|           5 | 1         | Subcategory level 1 |
|           6 | 5         | Subcategory level 2 |
|           7 | 6         | Subcategory level 3 |
|           8 | 2         | Subcategory level 1 |
|           9 | 3         | Subcategory level 1 |
|          10 | 4         | Subcategory level 1 |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Users Table:

```
+---------+-------+
| USER_ID | NAME  |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | Ben   |
|       2 | Frank |
+---------+-------+
```

Orders Table:

```
+----------+-------------+---------+
| ORDER_ID | CATEGORY_ID | USER_ID |
+----------+-------------+---------+
|        1 |           1 |       1 |
|        2 |           7 |       2 |
+----------+-------------+---------+
```

I want to get the information of every category and subcategory given an `order_id`.

E.g:

Given `order_id = 2`, find every category and subcategory:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| CATEGORY_ID | PARENT_ID |     DESCRIPTION     |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
|           1 | (null)    | Category 1          |
|           5 | 1         | Subcategory level 1 |
|           6 | 5         | Subcategory level 2 |
|           7 | 6         | Subcategory level 3 |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

I tried using `CONNECT BY` as you can see in the following [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73681d4/10), but it gives me a lot of "useless" rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> select c.category_id, c.parent_id, c.description
  2  from categories c
  3  start with c.category_id = (select o.category_id from orders o
  4                              where o.order_id = 2)
  5  connect by c.category_id = prior c.parent_id
  6  order by c.category_id;

CATEGORY_ID  PARENT_ID DESCRIPTION
----------- ---------- -------------------------
          1            Category 1
          5          1 Subcategory level 1
          6          5 Subcategory level 2
          7          6 Subcategory level 3

SQL>
```

Comment: It worked. I'm having a bit of problem if tables have more rows and if I filter orders by user, but thanks.